# Generate all possible numpad/keypad sequences

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I am trying to generate all possible keypad sequences (7 digit length only right now). For example if the mobile keypad looks like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
  0
```

Some of the possible sequences can be:

> 123698
>   147896
>   125698
>   789632

The requirement is that the each digit of number should be neighbor of previous digit.

Here is how I am planning to start this:

The information about the neighbor changes from keypad to keypad so we have to hardcode it like this:

```
neighbors = {0: 8, 1: [2,4], 2: [1,3,5], 3: [2,6], 4: [1,5,7], 5: [2,4,6,8], 6: [3,5,9], 7: [4,8], 8: [7,5,9,0], 9: [6,8]}
```

I will be traversing through all digits and will append one of the possible neighbors to it until required length is achieved.

EDIT: Updated neighbors, no diagonals allowed
EDIT 2: Digits can be reused

Comment: So, what's your question? You seem to understand the problem and you've made a start on the solution. What do you need help with? As a possible hint, note that all the 7-digit sequences can be found by caculating all the 6-digit sequences then adding all possible next moves to each of those. All the 6 digit sequences can be foudn by calculating all the 5-digit sequences...

Comment: You are being very inconsistent with your neighbors.  You show that 0 only has 1 neighbor, while 1 has 3.  Do you count diagonals or not?  If so, 2 should have 5 neighbors, if not, 1 should only have 2 neighbors, etc.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893470/generate-10-digit-number-using-a-phone-keypad, except neighbors are defined differently.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Jeff B, not counting diagonals. Changed!

Comment: Can numbers be used more than once in a given sequence, or is this like Boggle where each can only be used once?

Comment: Looks like a numeric Boggle solver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
 neighbors = {0: [8], 
             1: [2,4], 
             2: [1,4,3], 
             3: [2,6], 
             4: [1,5,7], 
             5: [2,4,6,8], 
             6: [3,5,9], 
             7: [4,8], 
             8: [7,5,9,0], 
             9: [6,8]}


def get_sequences(n):
    if not n:
        return
    stack = [(i,) for i in  range(10)]
    while stack:
        cur = stack.pop()
        if len(cur) == n:
            yield cur
        else:
            stack.extend(cur + (d, ) for d in neighbors[cur[-1]]) 

print list(get_sequences(3))
```

This will produce all possible sequences. You didn't mention if you wanted ones that have cycles in them, for example `(0, 8, 9, 8)` so I left them in. If you don't want them, then just use

```
 stack.extend(cur + (d, ) 
              for d in neighbors[cur[-1]]
              if d not in cur)
```

Note that I made the entry for `0` a list with one element instead of just an integer. This is for consistency. It's very nice be able to index into the dictionary and know that you're going to get a list back.

Also note that this isn't recursive. Recursive functions are **great** in languages that properly support them. In Python, you should almost always manage a stack like I demonstrate here. It's just as easy as a recursive solution and sidesteps function call overhead (python doesn't support tail recursion) and maximum recursion depth concerns.

Answer (score 1):

```
neighbors = {0: [8], 1: [2,5,4], 2: [1,4,3], 3: [2,5,6], 4: [1,5,7], 5: [2,4,6,8], 6: [3,5,9], 7: [4,5,8], 8: [7,5,9,0], 9: [6,5,8]}

def gen_neighbor_permutations(n, current_prefix, available_digit_set, removed_digits=set(), unique_digits=False):
    if n == 0:
            print current_prefix
            return
    for d in available_digit_set:
            if unique_digits:
                    gen_neighbor_permutations(n-1, current_prefix + str(d), set(neighbors[d]).difference(removed_digits), removed_digits.union(set([d])), unique_digits=True )
            else:
                    gen_neighbor_permutations(n-1, current_prefix + str(d), set(neighbors[d]).difference(removed_digits) )

gen_neighbor_permutations(n=3, current_prefix='', available_digit_set=start_set)
```

I also couldn't help but notice that in your examples, none of the digits are reused. If you want that, then you would use the `unique_digits = True` option; this will disallow recursion on digits that are already used.

+1 What a fun puzzle. I hope this works for you!

```
gen_neighbor_permutations(n=3, current_prefix='', available_digit_set=start_set, unique_digits = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion isn't really much of an issue here because the sequence is relatively short as are the choices for each digit except the first -- so there appear to "only" be 4790 possibilities disallowing diagonals. This is written as an iterator to eliminate the need to create and return a large container with all possibilities produced in it.

It occurred to me that an additional benefit of the data-driven approach of storing the neighbor adjacency information in a data structure (as the OP suggested) was that besides easily supporting different keypads, it also makes controlling whether diagonals are allowed or not trivial.

I debated briefly about whether to make it a list instead of a dictionary for faster lookups, but realized that doing so would make it more difficult to adapt to produce sequences other than digits (and likely wouldn't make it significantly faster anyway).

```
adjacent = {1: [2,4],   2: [1,3,4],   3: [2,6],
            4: [1,5,7], 5: [2,4,6,8], 6: [3,5,9],
            7: [4,8],   8: [0,5,7,9], 9: [6,8],
                        0: [8]}

def adj_sequences(ndigits):
    seq = [None]*ndigits  # pre-allocate

    def next_level(i):
        for neighbor in adjacent[seq[i-1]]:
            seq[i] = neighbor
            if i == ndigits-1:  # last digit?
                yield seq
            else:
                for digits in next_level(i+1):
                    yield digits

    for first_digit in range(10):
        seq[0] = first_digit
        for digits in next_level(1):
            yield digits

cnt = 1
for digits in adj_sequences(7):
    print '{:d}: {!r}'.format(cnt, ''.join(map(str,digits)))
    cnt += 1
```

Comment: This is probably a better solution to the problem than mine.

Answer (score 0):

That's a classic recursive algorithm.  Some pseudo code to show the concept:

```
function(numbers) { 
  if (length(numbers)==7) { 
    print numbers; 
    return; 
  } 
  if (numbers[last]=='1') { 
    function(concat(numbers,  '2')); 
    function(concat(numbers,  '4')); 
    return; 
  } 
  if (numbers[last]==='2') { 
    function(concat(numbers,  '1')); 
    function(concat(numbers,  '3')); 
    function(concat(numbers,  '5')); 
    return; 
  } 
  ...keep going with a condition for each digit..
}
```

Comment: Is this how people actually program in non dynamic languages? Why not just use a hash table into lists of neighboring digits like OP suggested? You don't even need first class functions for that.

Comment: @aaron, some people just program like that. It doesn't matter if the language is dynamic or not. eg, your own answer here doesn't use any dynamic features.

Comment: This solution is really tightly coupled to the keypad layout, especially since the OP mentioned that "The information about the neighbor changes from keypad to keypad"  Not going to -1 since it's not strictly wrong, but it's not very reusable for other key layouts.

Comment: It's psuedo code.  The purpose is to show the algorithm in an easily readable format and not how you actually implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
neighbors = {0: [8], 1: [2,5,4], 2: [1,4,3], 3: [2,5,6], 4: [1,5,7], 5: [2,4,6,8], 6: [3,5,9], 7: [4,5,8], 8: [7,5,9,0], 9: [6,5,8]}

def keyNeighborsRec(x, length):
    if length == 0:
            print x
            return
    for i in neighbors[x%10]:
            keyNeighborsRec(x*10+i,length-1)


def keyNeighbors(l):
    for i in range(10):
            keyNeighborsRec(i,length-1)

keyNeighbors(7)
```

its really easy without the neighbor condition...

```
def keypadSequences(length):
    return map(lambda x: '0'*(length-len(repr(x)))+repr(x), range(10**length))

keypadSequences(7)
```

Comment: That's just printing all the possible number sequences.  There's some rules in the problem about what the next number in the sequence can be.

Comment: yes, read my above comment.  i noticed the neighbors thing afterwords.  this would be the answer without neighbor conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
states = [
    [8],
    [2, 4],
    [1, 3, 5],
    [2, 6],
    [1, 5, 7],
    [2, 4, 6, 8],
    [3, 5, 9],
    [4, 8],
    [5, 7, 9, 0],
    [6, 8]
]

def traverse(distance_left, last_state):
    if not distance_left:
        yield []
    else:
        distance_left -= 1
        for s in states[last_state]:
            for n in traverse(distance_left, s):
                yield [s] + n

def produce_all_series():
    return [t for i in range(10) for t in traverse(7, i)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(produce_all_series())
```